# stream video from android to Azure Media Services

Tags: android, video-streaming, azure-media-services

Is it possible to stream a live video feed from the camera of an android phone. I haven't seen any information on Microsoft's website regarding the possibility of live streaming from an android phone.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Media Services supports RTMP ingest. There are open source RTMP libraries for Android. You can build a capture and stream app using this libraries.
Unfortunately we don't provide a capture SDK at the moment.